# My url mapping is diverting my CSS pages

Tags: java, css, jsp, servlets, url-mapping

I am working on a Dynamic Web Application with simple Java, Eclipse, and Tomcat 7.

Until I made the below changes, everything worked perfectly.

I recently added a home page Servlet `Home.java` and home page jsp `Home.jsp` and mapped the servlet to the URL `/` in the web.xml like

```
 <servlet>
        <display-name>Home</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my_proj.servlets.Home</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The Servlet `Home.java` looks like:

```
public class Home extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Servlet \"Home\" doGet working");
        System.out.println("PathInfo: " + request.getRequestURL());
        //If logged in, go to home page
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/resources/jsp/home.jsp").forward(request, response);
        //If not, go to login/register page
        // TODO
    }

}
```

And the `Home.jsp` is quite long, but everything is working except the resources like CSS, images, etc. They are not being loaded by the page. I am referencing them with

```
<link href="/my_proj/resources/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**The Cause**

Because of the code I put in the `doGet` method above, I can see that the requests to find the CSS page are actually ending up at the `Home` servlet. For instance this is part of what I see in the console

```
Servlet "Home" doGet working
PathInfo: http://localhost:8080/my_proj/resources/css/custom.css
```

So my question is, how to I properly map my pages so as to not to cause this confusion? Or how do I separate my CSS from relying on this mapping system? I don't want web.xml to handle the mapping to these files.

Comment: Give your directory structure. it seems a path problem when you called css.

Answer (score 0):

Please give your directory structure, for example If your directory structure like :

Project Name\WebContent\css then just add following line to include css on your page :

```
<link href="css/fileName.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That's it, No need to provide full path : like Project Name\WebContent\css\fileName.css

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="/css/fileName.css" rel="stylesheet">
```